# Find the volume of the solid paraboloid of revolution

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, solid-of-revolution

Could anyone help me find the volume of the solid paraboloid of revolution
$$y=10-x^2-z^2, y\geq0$$

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I do not how to set as solved, could you help me ?

Comment: Take a look here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to visualize this differently. This is a body of revolution about the $y$-axis. Therefore we can think of this as the function $y(x)=10-x^2$ to be rotated about the $y$-axis. By Pappus's $2^{nd}$ Centroid theorem the volume is given the by the area multiplied by the path length of it centroid upon rotation, or

$$V=2\pi RA$$

For rotation about the $y$-axis$ the centroid is given by

$$R=\frac{1}{A}\int x\cdot y(x)~dx$$

thus

$$
\begin{align}
V
&=2\pi \int_0^{\sqrt{10}} x(10-x^2)~dx\\
&=2\pi ~\left(5x^2-\frac{x^4}{4}\right)\biggr|_0^{\sqrt{10}}\\
&=50\pi
\end{align}
$$

This result has been verified numerically.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let's proceed by **cylindrical coordinates**:

$$x = r \cos{\theta}$$
$$z = r \sin{\theta}$$
$$y = y$$

> That is
>
> $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{10}\int_0^{\sqrt{10-y}}r \, dr \, dy\, d\theta $$

Comment: Could you give me more details about the calculation?